# R: How to plot Line chart with multiple filterers. (R-shiny / flexdashboard)

Tags: r, charts, shiny

R: How to plot Line chart with multiple filterers. (R-shiny / flexdashboard).

I want to plot line chart with average present value from total no. of events employees have attended.

**Exmp:**
Total events for employee A in 01/2019 is 4 where he was only present in 1 then it should display 25% result for that month. ((1/4) * 100) %

Here is the sample data but in actuality there are 100+ employees,
So result should be required as line colour code by employee name.

Data set like:

```
Employee        Status          Month_Yr
A               PRESENT         01/2019
C               PRESENT         01/2019
B               PRESENT         01/2019
C               PRESENT         02/2019
D               PRESENT         03/2019
A               PRESENT         01/2019
B               PRESENT         03/2019
C               PRESENT         01/2019
B               ABSENT          01/2019
D               ABSENT          01/2019
A               ABSENT          01/2019
C               PRESENT         02/2019
B               PRESENT         01/2019
A               PRESENT         02/2019
A               ABSENT          02/2019
D               ABSENT          03/2019
C               PRESENT         01/2019
C               ABSENT          01/2019
C               ABSENT          01/2019
A               ABSENT          02/2019
C               ABSENT          04/2019
B               ABSENT          01/2019
```

Code I tried:

```
sub_data5 <-mutate(sub_data5, ontime = ifelse(sub_data5$Status=="PRESENT","Y","N"))


sub_data5 <- sub_data5 %>% 
    count(year_month, Employee, ontime,year,Month) %>% 
    group_by(year_month, Employee,year,Month) %>% 
    mutate(Prop = (n/sum(n))*100)

sub_data5$`Prop`  <- as.integer(sub_data5$`Prop`)

ggplot(sub_data5, aes(x=year_month, y=Prop, group=Employee, color=Employee)) +
  geom_line()
```

But I want to display a line plot with filters of year_month,Employee,year,Month.

Like we get filters in rpivottable check attached Image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this code i got my result.

```
# Calculate total count of status and add new column for its percentage value.
sub_data5 <- sub_data5 %>% 
    count(Month_yr, Employee, Status) %>% 
    group_by(Month_yr, Employee) %>% 
    mutate(Percent = (n/sum(n))*100)

# Convert Percentage decimal to string 
sub_data5$`Percent `  <- (as.integer(sub_data5$`Percent`)+" %")

# Drop row values with ABSENT
sub_data5<-sub_data5[!(sub_data5$Status=="ABSENT"),]

#Employee can't use in plot because it's used as grouping so convert DF in to new DF
sub_data10 <- as.data.frame(sub_data5)

# Plot line chart.
plo <- ggplot(data=sub_data10, aes(x=Month_yr, y=Precent, group=Employee, colour=Employee)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()

fig <- ggplotly(plo)

fig
```

Comment: But not getting required filters